# How to save a SELECT Data on DB - LARAVEL

Tags: database, laravel, select

I would like to save a Select data on my DB, but at DB saves the value for example in this case "0" or "1". How can I save "Yes" or "No" data??

This is my select:

```
{!!Form::select('airbag',['Yes', 'No'], null,['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>''])!!}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that:

```
<?php $my_array = ['Yes', 'No'] ?>
{!! Form::select('airbag', array_combine($my_array, $my_array), null,['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'']) !!}
```

or if you want to flip between keys & values

```
!! Form::select('airbag', array_flip(['Yes', 'No']), null,['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'']) !!}
```

Look and inspect element of your browser to make sure from that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
{!!Form::select('airbag',['Yes', 'No'], null,['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>''])!!}
```

to

```
{!!Form::select('airbag',['Yes' => 'Yes', 'No' => 'No'], null,['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>''])!!}'
```